# django 4: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'

Tags: python, django, object

database is ok, migrations created

problems with it **object_list = Post.published.all() **

Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

Views:

```
def post_list(request):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'page': page,
                   'posts': posts})
```

Migrations:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('publish', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published')], default='draft', max_length=10)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

urls main app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^blog/', include(('blog.urls', 'blog'), namespace='blog')),
]
```

urls blog app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    re_path(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]
```

*first time per stack overflow, sorry for the mistakes*

registered in the database column "published".
idk what's the problem

Comment: did you create any custom model manager name as published? You can't call publish like this without custom model manager. If you are trying to display only published post you can try this `object_list = Post.objects.filter(status='published')`

Comment: Your model has a `publish` field, but not a `published` field...

Answer (score 2):

As dostogircse171 pointed out, create a custom manager by subclassing `models.Manager` and defining a method to filter published posts then, add the custom manager to your Post model be able to access the `Post.published.all()`

Try this:

```
from django.db import models

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')    
    published = PublishedManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your orm syntax is wrong `object_list = Post.published.all()` here in your `post_list` function of views, The correct syntax is `object_list = Post.objects.all(status="published")`, and then your code will look like this:

```
def post_list(request):
    object_list = Post.objects.all(status="published") # ----->> Change here
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'page': page,
                   'posts': posts})
```